# Find $\mathbb{E}[X]$ given a discrete $2$ variable probability function

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let
$$ \displaystyle{ P_{X,Y}(n,m) = c e^{-m} \frac{ m^n}{ n!} \binom{146}{m} } $$
for all $ n\ge 0,0\le m \le 146$ and a constant $ c>0 $ find $ \mathbb{E}[x]$

What I tried doing is getting $ \mathbb{P}[X=x]$ by using the marginal distribution formula as : $$ \mathbb{P}\left(X=x\right)=\sum_{y=0}^{y=146}ce^{-y}\frac{y^{x}}{x!}\binom{146}{y}=\frac{c}{x!}\sum_{y=0}^{y=146}e^{-y}\cdot y^{x}\binom{146}{y}=\frac{c}{x!}\sum_{y=0}^{146}\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^{y}\cdot y^{x}\binom{146}{y} $$
However I don't know how to calculate this sum for all $x\ne0$, if it had no $ y^x $ I could use the binomial theorem nicely.
Where is my mistake here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we need $c$.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{146}c e^{-m} \frac{ m^n}{ n!} \binom{146}{m} =1$$.

So $$\sum_{m=0}^{146}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c e^{-m} \frac{ m^n}{ n!} \binom{146}{m}=1$$.

So $$\sum_{m=0}^{146}c\binom{146}{m}=1\implies c\cdot 2^{146}=1\implies c=\frac{1}{2^{146}}$$.

So $$\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{1}{2^{146}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{146}ne^{-m}\frac{m^{n}}{n!}\binom{146}{m}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2^{146}}\sum_{m=0}^{146}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}me^{-m}\frac{m^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\binom{146}{m}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2^{146}}\sum_{m=0}^{146}m\binom{146}{m}=\sum_{m=1}^{146}\frac{1}{2^{146}}\frac{m\cdot 146!}{m!(146-m)!}$$

$$=\frac{146}{2^{146}}\sum_{m=1}^{146}\frac{145!}{(m-1)!(145-(m-1))!}=\frac{146}{2^{146}}\sum_{m=0}^{145}\binom{145}{m}=\frac{146}{2^{146}}\cdot 2^{145}$$

$$=\frac{146}{2}=73$$

The change of order of summation is justified by Fubini as the summands are positive.

Comment: You forgot $m$ on the third line below the third "So".

Comment: @FreeZe thanks .